# Is it possible to have a vector space in which $\vec{v}=-\vec{v}$, yet $\vec{v}\neq \vec{0}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, field-theory, finite-fields

Silly question. I was pondering whether given a vector space $V$ over $K$ and a vector $\vec{v}$ such that $\vec{v}=-\vec{v}$ then $\vec{v}\neq \vec{0}$. This is certainly true as long as $1/2\in K$ (or, equivalently, if $1+1\neq 0$ in $K$), yet what if this condition is not met?

Is it possible to have a vector space in which $\vec{v}=-\vec{v}$, yet $\vec{v}\neq \vec{0}$?

Comment: If $1=-1$, then any nonzero vector $v$ satisfies $v=-v$.

Comment: Take $K=\mathbb F_2$, the field of two elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $1+1=0$, then $1=-1$ and hence $v=-v$ for *all* vectors $v$.

Answer (score 3):

From $\vec{v} = -\vec{v}$, we get $(1+1)\vec{v}=2\vec{v}=\vec{0}$.

- If $K$ has characteristic $2$ (that is, if $1+1=0$, than $\vec{v}=-\vec{v}$ for all vectors $\vec{v}$.
- Otherwise, we multiply the equation with $2^{-1}$, and get $\vec{v} = 0$